# SSIS 2016 - ErrorColumn is 0 (zero)

Tags: ssis

I have a package with a bunch of oledb Destinations, using SSIS 2016 - which is supposed to show the exact column that generated the error.The ErrorColumn shows (0) zero, therefore I am unable to trap the column that generated the error.

Using the script below (with code that assigns "Unknown column" but it does not help, it just avoids the script fail):

```
public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
{
    //IDTSComponentMetaData130 componentMetaData = ComponentMetaData as IDTSComponentMetaData130;
    //var component130 = this.ComponentMetaData as IDTSComponentMetaData130;
    //if (component130 != null)
    //{
    //    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(component130.GetIdentificationStringByID(Row.ErrorColumn));
    //    Row.ErrorColumnName = component130.GetIdentificationStringByID(Row.ErrorColumn);
    //}
    IDTSComponentMetaData130 componentMetaData = ComponentMetaData as IDTSComponentMetaData130;
    if (componentMetaData != null)
    {
        //
        if (Row.wkpErrorColumn != 0)
            Row.wkpErrorColumnName = componentMetaData.GetIdentificationStringByID(Row.wkpErrorColumn);
        else
            Row.wkpErrorColumnName = "Unknown column";
    }
    else
    {
        Row.wkpErrorColumnName = "Cannot determine";
    }
    Row.wkpErrorDescription = ComponentMetaData.GetErrorDescription(Row.wkpErrorCode);
}
```

Comment: I haven't used this `componentMetaData.GetIdentificationStringByID` but perhaps the ID is a 0 based ID instead of 1 based in which case you would not want to check `Row.wkpErrorColumn != 0` but rather `Row.wkpErrorColumn != null` at least that is the comparison at the bottom of this page: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ssis/2015/11/27/error-column-improvements-for-ssis-data-flow-updated-for-rc2/

Comment: Redirect errors and add a Data Viewer. The latest SSDT versions decode the error code and display the actual error message

Comment: That is the problem. I added a DataViewer, But it does show the Column being zero.

Answer (score 3):

In SSIS 2008 (and I believe also SSIS 2016), a zero error column identifies an error that affects the entire row. In the example below, I have created a package that contains only 1 data flow task in the control flow and redirecting all errors and truncations to the error output. Placed a row count task just to have somewhere to send them to.
Also placed data viewers in both error flows to see the data coming out of it.

In a package consuming data from a flat file into an OLE DB Destination:

[image]

Using these values as input data

[image]

And having name as the PK of the table

[image]

We get a PK violation, check the error description and the error column

[image]

**So when the error affects the entire record, it gets an error column value of 0.**

Hope this helps.

Comment: This might be it (affecting the entire row). I still think it should display the column that is creating the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found that

When the error is generated by the PK, the error affect the entire row, and the error column is 0

When the error is generated by a Fk, The error affect only the column, and you get the error column value different then 0